# How best to loop through multiple functions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a more concise way to loop through a number of conditions than this?

```
def is_this_whole_thing_true?
  result = false
  result = true if condition_1?
  result = true if condition_2?
  result = true if condition_3?
  result = true if condition_4?
  result = true if condition_5?
  result = true if condition_6?
  result = true if condition_7?
  result
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply put && condition here like:

```
def is_this_whole_thing_true?
  condition_1? && condition_2? && condition_3? && ...
end
```

Infact, what you are trying to do in the method is return `true` if any of the condition is true, then use `||`

```
def is_this_whole_thing_true?
  condition_1? || condition_2? || condition_3? || ...
end
```

An advantage of this is, it won't check all of the conditions, as soon as any one of the condition turns out to be `true`, it will return.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: Actually, I like this version (with the `||`) best, so I'll mark it as the correct answer. It works like a charm by the way and behaves exactly as expected.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care to create a whole array I think this is the best option

```
def is_this_whole_thing_true?
  conditions = [condition1?, condition2?, condition3?, condition4?]
  conditions.any?
end
```

Comment: Right. This is the way to do it.

Comment: curious to know why it is the best?

Comment: From a readability point of view. In my opinion, obviously :)

Comment: ohhkay..I was thinking on the lines of `performance` where I couldn't convince myself creating array of methods unnecessarily.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I don't if there is a different solution that is both readable and with no array creation.